# Scroll to certain height of a page javascript

Tags: javascript

I've a very simple one line code that checks whether user has scrolled to the bottom of the page, I want to change it a little bit & find whether user has reached the footer of the page. And height of footer is somewhat 350px.

Here's my code:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == ($(document).height())
{
...
}
```

This works like a charm (loads more content on scroll event), but if I do like this:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == ($(document).height()-350))
```

This doesn't work. When I attempt to `alert('$(document).height()-350')`. It gives a perfect alert.

Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you are missing some brackets ()

Comment: you are probably scrolling more than 1 pixel at a time and just skip the equality point. make it a `>=` and it should work

Comment: @Banana That was a pretty awesome thing, it worked, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Is there any margin on the footer? What you're checking for is very exact, should use >= as suggested above.

Comment: You can comment this as an answer & I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you are probably scrolling more than 1 pixel at a time and just skip the equality point. make it a >= and it should work:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= ($(document).height()-350))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()-350)
```

Also you have '(' char in front of $(document).height() which needs to be removed

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `>=` instead of `==`, otherwise you must be pixel-perfect in your scroll in order for the event to fire.

Give this a try. You can use the `.offset().top` of your footer element to get the Y-position relative to the document.

```
var scrollBottom = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
var footerTop = $('#footer').offset().top; // change selector as needed

if ( scrollBottom >= footerTop ) {
  alert("hello footer");
}
```